# Is ember-data an adequate solution for managing communication between a single page app and a C++ (QT) backend?

Tags: ember.js, webkit, ember-data

I'm developing a standalone application that uses c++ to crunch some numbers, and a single web app as front-end, using ember.

I've thought that I could create an ember-data adapter to handle communication between javascript and c++. The communication would be then driven by changes in the model: When a user action triggers a change in the model, then some action may be required in the backend.

Example:

A model could be: Date {day of the year, day of month, month}. 
When the user changes any of these parameters, the updated model is passed to the backend, which updates the other two. After the backend has updated all the model parameters, it would trigger a refresh on the frontend.

The backend operation could be much more complex, but that is the basic idea: some properties depend on others, but they are calculated by the backend, on the other side of the ember-data adapter.

The advantage is that in the future it'd be simple to reuse the frontend, by simply switching the adapter, so it may be that a browser based front end can be linked with a more powerful backend on a HTTP server.

However, I'm not sure this is an adequate use of ember-data. I'd be using ember-data for data persistence, but not only for that, as the models are also modified by the backend.

So, the question is, do you think this scheme makes sense, or is this a bad idea? In the later case, could someone please indicate some better alternative?

Thanks,
Eloy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that scheme makes sense. It is not uncommon for ember-data to be used with systems that both persist and modify data on the backend.

If that modification happens quickly, the backend can trigger frontend refresh in it's response to an update. Otherwise like you said it could trigger a refresh on the frontend. I've seen both of these approaches working for ember-data apps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the case of my application (a simulation), the modification could take some time (>10 seconds), and partial results would be available at different points in that period.
So, according to your answer, the backend could inform the front end of the start of the calculation in the response to the update, and then trigger one or several refresh events until the calculation is completed.

Comment: To complete my previous comment: 
I'll use data-ember to mediate all communication between the backend and frontend. I'm happy to have only one bridge between C++ and Javascript in the app.